# Django Custom User Admin Panel won't log in

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I just started a new Django project and I wanted to create my own customer user model instead of using the default. I pretty much followed the one in the documentation for 2.1 (my version of Django) except I added more fields and date_of_birth is called 'dob' and isn't required. But then when I create the superuser account, I can't log into the admin panel. It says, "Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

Here is my code:

users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


# Create your models here.
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    # python manage.py createuser
    def create_user(self, email: str, password: str=None) -> 'User':
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address.')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    # python manage.py createsuperuser
    def create_superuser(self, email, password) -> 'User':
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'), help_text=_('An email address'), max_length=127, unique=True, null=False, blank=False
    )
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), help_text=_('The user\'s given name'), blank=False, max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(
        _('last name'), help_text=_('The user\'s surname or family name'), blank=False, max_length=32
    )
    dob = models.DateField(_('date of birth'), help_text=_('User\'s date of birth'), blank=False, null=True)
    hometown = models.CharField(_('hometown'), help_text=_('Hometown'), blank=True, max_length=64)
    country = models.CharField(_('country'), help_text=_('Country'), blank=True, max_length=64)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_staff

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_staff

    @property
    def is_staff(self) -> bool:
        """
        Is the user a member of staff?

        :return: If the user is an admin, then True. Else False
        """
        return self.is_admin
```

I also changed my settings.py file to read:

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

and I made sure the app ('myproject.users.apps.UsersConfig') is added to the INSTALLED_APPS list. Note: my apps are all located one folder in, unlike the tutorial default. Ie:

```
myproject/
   |-----> users/
              |----->models.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed one thing in `User` model,
Change `is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)` to `is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)`
Hence your model be like,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # other fields
```

From the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active),
`is_active`

> Boolean. Designates whether this user account should be considered
>   active. We recommend that you set this flag to False instead of
>   deleting accounts; that way, if your applications have any foreign
>   keys to users, the foreign keys won’t break.

Comment: Thanks! I had changed this but I suppose for superusers they should be active. Doh!